# How to subscribe to all question activities

Tags: feature-request

Really newbie question. Is there a simple way to get notifications inside  my inbox about all new comments, and answers for a question?

Is the favorite star the answer for me?

Comment: Ugh, can't imagine favoriting everything. Does http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61/rss-feed-for-magento-stackexchange?rq=1 help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an RSS feed for any given question by clicking on the "question feed" link at the bottom right of the question page.

Or, if you're into manipulating URLs by hand: for the question

`http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1234/title-of-example-question`

the feed URL is

`http://magento.stackexchange.com/feeds/question/1234`

There are a couple of other hacky workarounds and incomplete solutions, but this is the best solution we offer that works for any given question.

Comment: I've accepted the answer, as haven't found any better alternative.